# What does sizeof(int) return in this case?

Tags: c++, c, sizeof, turbo-c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{   
    if(sizeof(int)>=-2)    
        printf("True");
    else
        printf("False");
}
```

When I am trying to compile this piece of code using Turbo C++ it is returning False instead of True .
But when I tried to print the value of int the program is returning 2.

How can this be possible ? while `sizeof(int)` is returning 2 and yes 2>=-2  .

Comment: Why do you use TurboC++ ? It is unmaintained, and is not standard conforming.... Try [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), e.g. on Linux.

Comment: [Integer promotion rules.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563000/implicit-type-conversion-rules-in-c-operators)

Comment: You can always `std::cout << sizeof(int) << std::endl;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the return type of sizeof operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870192/what-is-the-return-type-of-sizeof-operator)

Comment: Please use `int main`, `return 0` and use some `c compiler` if you intend to write C code.

Comment: @GyaptiJain `return 0` is not neccesary in `main` in C++ programs.

Comment: @GyaptiJain No need for `return 0` from `main` in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza Not necessary, but good style none the less.

Comment: @jrok You are right. In C++ it is not required, but just for the sake of good programming style. Moreover it appears that Abdul wants to write a C code but is using (Turbo)C++ compiler.

Comment: Trick question - (almost) everyone knows that the size of something can't be negative.

Comment: I remain unconvinced that `return 0` is "good style".  any experienced c++ programmer is aware of this behavior

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why sizeof(int) is not greater than -1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466857/why-sizeofint-is-not-greater-than-1)

Comment: @Gyapti in C99 you don't need to `return 0` either

Answer (score 16):

`sizeof(int)` is replaced with type `std::size_t` which is unsigned <strike>on most of the implementations</strike>.

Comparing signed with unsigned leads strange result because of signed being promoted to unsigned.

You can get sensible result as shown below

```
if(static_cast<int>(sizeof(int)) >= -2)
```

If you are working on a `C` compiler

```
if((int)sizeof(int) >= -2)
```

Compiling your code with some warning flags `-Wall` for example should most possibly warn about signed/unsigned comparison. (If you are not ignoring the warnings)

Comment: which any decent compiler would warn you about.

Comment: @dandan78: The question isn't about a decent compiler.

Comment: `std::size_t` is required by the standard to be an unsigned type.

Comment: Can you please re-write the code for me so that it returns true. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `if(1)` would be another way to get sensible results, since `sizeof` can never give a negative result

Comment: @M.M Actually. `if(1)` and `int main()` make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The type of `sizeof` is `size_t` (`typedef unsigned int size_t`). `unsigned int` compared with an signed may cause wrong answer.

Comment: Not necessarily `unsigned int`.  `unsigned long` and `unsigned long long` are probably just as frequent, if not more.  The only requirement is that it be an unsigned integral type.

Comment: Can you please re-write the code for me so that it returns true. Thanks in advance.

Comment: on 64-bit systems it's most probably `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`