# Why result of std::size not compile time OR is not size_t?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, visual-c++-2019

On Visual C++ 2019:

The following code renders the warning:

`warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'DWORD', possible loss of data`

```
HANDLE events[2];
WaitForMultipleObjects(std::size(events), events, FALSE, INFINITE);
```

But using `_countof(events)` won't give any warning. Note that `std::size`'s template overload function is called. 
This one:

```
template<class _Ty,
    size_t _Size> inline
    constexpr size_t size(const _Ty(&)[_Size]) _NOEXCEPT
    {   // get dimension for array
    return (_Size);
    }
```

Which essentially **is** returning a `size_t`, and the function is `constexpr`. And that's why array declaration works:

```
HANDLE Events[2];
int arr[std::size(Events)];
```

But following code won't compile without warning:

```
DWORD sz1 = std::size(Events);
```

This is okay:

```
DWORD sz2= _countof(Events);
```

Any specific reason, or a compiler bug?

*Relevant:*
[What is the return type of sizeof operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870192/what-is-the-return-type-of-sizeof-operator)

**EDIT**, Interestingly, these would also work fine:

```
HANDLE events[2];
constexpr size_t s1 = sizeof(Events) / sizeof(Events[0]);
constexpr size_t s2 = std::size(Events);
```

The variables `s1` and `s2` are taken as true compile-time values, but not `std::size()`'s result itself!

Comment: "*The variables s1 and s2 are taken as true compile-time values, but not std::size()'s result itself!*" What is a "true compile-time value, and how is `std::size()` different from that?

Comment: @NicolBolas A `constexpr` function may not result in compile-time constant

Comment: Yes, `constexpr` functions can be executed at runtime. But that didn't answer my question: what do you consider to be a "true compile-time value"?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the warning messages it's a complaint about converting *from* the type `size_t` (the result of `std::size(Events)`) *to* `DWORD` (the type of `sz1`).

The problem is that on a 64-bit system `size_t` is typically a 64-bit unsigned integer type. But Windows define [`DWORD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types#DWORD) as a *32* bit unsigned integer type.

That the use of `_countof` doesn't generate a warning might be because of implementation-specific behavior of the MSVC compiler.

Comment: This also doesn't answer my question. Why `_countof` or `sizeof/sizeof` at  WFSO call would work fine, but not `constexpr std::size()` ?

Answer (score 0):

`DWORD` is always 32-bit unsigned on Windows.

`size_t` is typically a 64-bit unsigned long long with a 64-bit compiler.  Switch your build to 32-bit and it's a 32-bit unsigned int.

Assigning a 64-bit int to a 32-bit - yep, that's a warning condition.

What's weird is this:

```
WaitForMultipleObjects(sizeof(events) / sizeof(events[0]), events, FALSE, INFINITE);
```

Compiles without issue.  I'm guessing it's because the compiler can infer the type of that *const* expression reduces to unsigned int or smaller.

But this:

```
auto count = sizeof(events) / sizeof(events[0]);
WaitForMultipleObjects(count, events, FALSE, INFINITE);
```

Generates a nearly identical warning since `count` evaluates to a 64-bit unsigned long long.

But this will also compile without warning:

```
const auto count = sizeof(events) / sizeof(events[0]);
WaitForMultipleObjects(count, events, FALSE, INFINITE);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't answer my question. If `sizeof(events) / sizeof(events[0])` is placed at WFMO call, it would compile fine. `_countof`, `ARRAY_SIZE` would also. Why not `std::size` ?

Comment: @Ajay - I see what you are asking. When I step through the assembly in the debugger, it appears that the call to std::size is indeed a function call to the template function in `<xutility>` and not inlined.

Comment: Does not explain why it still warrants a warning in release - when it's clearly inlined.

Comment: `constexpr` function, in that context, is behaving like "consteval". Function call won't be made (there is template based return value resolution). Let it be inline or not, that's for other contexts. BTW, did you see  `template []` version for assembly code?