# Why does the sizeof operator in C gives different output in case of NOT operation?

Tags: c, memory

I am new to programming, and was introduced with the `sizeof` operator of C. Playing with it, I found the following interesting thing:

```
long long int a = 100;

printf("%d %d\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(!a));  // Output : 8 1
```

I understand `sizeof(a)` (in my system) is 8. But I could not understand why  `sizeof(!a)` becomes 1.

Is it because !a becomes 0, which is stored as `char`?

Moreover, The following code increased my confusion even more:

```
long long int a = 100;
char b = 9;

printf("%d %d %d %d\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(b), sizeof(a+b), sizeof(!a+b)); // Output : 8 1 8 4
```

Can anyone explain me, what is happening here? Due to typecasting, char should be converted into long long int, right? If so, I understand the `8 1 8` part of the output. But why sizeof(!a+b) is 4?

According to [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19870234), `sizeof()` returns `size_t`, which is 4 bytes in size. But couldn't get the answer of my query from it.

Comment: The output should not be `1`  , you are most likely running a C++ compiler (C++ is a different language to C). However the whole program causes undefined behaviour due to incorrect format specifier in printf, so anything can happen.

Comment: @M.M yes, it's a C++ compiler. Also, thanks to you, I came to know that `bool` is data type in C++, but it's just an alias in C.

Comment: Don't mix up typecasting with conversion caused by implicit type promotion. A cast is always explicit and always done by the programmer with `(type)`. Apart from the bool vs int issue, there's implicit conversion, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules.

Comment: @steve C also has a bool data type, however in C the result of the `!` operator does not  have the bool data type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of the `!` operator has type `int`, so `sizeof(!a)` is the same as `sizeof(int)`.

This is documented in section 6.5.3.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the logical negation operator `!`:

> The  result  of  the  logical  negation  operator!is  0  if  the
> value  of  its  operand  compares unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its
> operand compares equal to 0.  **The result has type `int`.** The
> expression `!E` is equivalent to `(0==E)`.

On most systems a `int` is 4 bytes in size so `sizeof(int)` would evaluate to 4.  If you're getting 1 as the result of `sizeof(!a)` then you're probably using a C++ compiler where the result of `!` has type `bool`.

Comment: `I understand sizeof(a) (in my system) is 8. But I could not understand why sizeof(!a) becomes 1.`  than what is this behaviour ?

Comment: @UmarFarooq Are you using a c++ compiler?  If so, the result of `!` has type `bool`.